# How can I generalize this fact about scalar equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

Near a bifurcation point, a dynamical system will undergo what is called *critical slowing down* -- A loss in resilience to perturbation from equilibrium. See [here](http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/files/papers/others/2009/scheffer2009a.pdf) for more on this phenomenon.

A hallmark of this slowing down is an increase in the variance and lag-1 autocorrelation of a stochastically forced system.  As the system approaches a bifurcation point due to slow change in a control parameter, an increase in these statistics is also observed.

A quick argument for this can be made for scalar equations:

Assume there is repeated disturbance in the state variable after each time period $\Delta t$.  Between disturbances, the return to equilibrium is approximately exponential, with recovery speed $\lambda$.  This can be described as an autoregressive progress :

$$y_{n+1} = \exp(-\lambda \Delta t) y_n + \sigma\epsilon \>.$$

Here, $y_n$ is the state variables deviation from equilirbium, $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and  $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.  When written in this way, we see that the autocorrelation, $\alpha$ is equal to $\exp(-\lambda \Delta t$).  Assuming that $\lambda$ and $\Delta t$ are independant of $y_n$, then we can observe that the system undergoes critical slowing down, then the recovery speed $-\lambda \rightarrow 0^-$, hence the autocorrelation tends to 1 from below.

---

My question is: how can I extend this argument to systems of differential equations?